# Why can't I vote to close a question I've already voted to close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I tried to close vote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183726/headers-already-sent-in-php). But when I click on the close link the popup comes up, only without the radio buttons (just like it would when I would have already vc'ed) it. Other people can still cv it.

According to [ThiefMaster](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4238424#4238424) it was reopened by a mod. So I suspect I already cv'ed it before it was reopened by a mod. My questions are:

- Are my assumptions correct?
- Is it a "bug" that I cannot vote for it after it has been reopened (while others still can)?
- Shouldn't this behavior be changed?
- If not: why not?

Comment: I closed it again.  Someone re-asks that same question every couple of days.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Glad you feel my pain my friend :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's kind of hard to criticize when the asker posted in 2009

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: OK.  But [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957) is [the canonical one everybody links to.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f8028957%2f*%22&lq=1)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek It's not only about OP and I suspect you would know that. It's about other people getting to that question (including the "limited" answers). That was the reason it was closed, but for some  (perhaps valid) reason (that I don't understand) it was reopened this january.

Comment: `Post Reopened by Kev♦` back in January.

Comment: @Shog9 That title sounds as though the poster already knew the problem that the answers are pointing out...

Comment: @John: he *should have* - but regardless, the title was useless as it stood.

Comment: Ok, my bad. In my defence, it seemed illogical to be closing an old question as a dupe of one posted two years later. Also I wasn't aware that the 2011 post had become the canonical for *Headers already sent by PHP* type questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [Post Closed as "exact duplicate" by NikiC, ircmaxell, **PeeHaa**, edorian, Levi Morrison](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1183726/revisions)

You can only vote to close *once* on a question, no matter how many times it has been closed and re-opened.

(Also, you can only vote to re-open once, regardless of whether you've VTC'd).

Answer (score 8):

I believe it is by design that you can only ever vote to close a question once, and [you have, in fact, already voted to close it.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1183726/revisions)

[image]

From the [`/privileges` page on close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions):

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each individual user may only vote once in each direction in the cycle.

Comment: Wow. Didn't know it also turns up in revision. Learn something new everyday :-)

Comment: Seems like the real question now is: why has it been reopened :P

Comment: May be user thinks it is a good question and must be reopened so it is

Answer (score 5):

In the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1183726/revisions), you can see that you effectively voted to close before the question got reopened:

> **Post Closed** as "exact duplicate" by NikiC, ircmaxell, PeeHaa, edorian, Levi Morrison

You can only vote to close once to prevent **close/reopen wars**. It only takes 5 votes to close or reopen a question, so five users voting over and over again will effectively override whatever the community consensus might be.

Comment: In this case it was 1 mod effectively overriding the community for some reason.

Comment: @PeeHaa the question got a flag on it at the time complaining about it being closed as a dupe of a newer question.

Comment: Closing/re-opening wars is probably the first reason not to allow multiple VTC for a question.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks for elaborating.