# After voting to close, delete and reopen, I can't cast a close vote

Tags: feature-request, support, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete, vote-to-reopen

When the OP posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600165/cant-get-element-by-id), the contents looked like "AAAA AAAA AAAAAAAAA".
Obviously, no-one was going to understand this, so we downvoted and voted to close.
After closure, I immediately voted to delete the question.
A few seconds later, the OP updated the question. I voted to re-open, and a few minutes later, the question was re-opened.

I've just reviewed the Q&A, and it's garbage:

- The question is unclear (the fiddle doesn't match the question's code).
- The only answer was was invalidated after the question was updated again (it pointed to a typo).
- The invalid answer was accepted with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600165/cant-get-element-by-id#comment15354478_11600224) *"My problem was somewhere else but I did learn that JSFiddle needs the tag table. thanks"* (note: has nothing to do with the question).

For these reasons, I decided to cast a close vote, which summoned the following screen:
[image: You have already voted to close this question]

As you can see, **there are no pending close votes, but the screen still shows that I have already cast a close vote.** This looks like a bug (possibly caused by my previous delete vote?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - this is correct behavior (AKA [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)) - as stated on the privileges page for [Cast close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) -

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each
>   individual user may only vote once in each direction in the cycle.

Your first close vote was the only close vote you could make on that post.   It is irrelevant that the post was reopened because you had previously voted to close.

---

I'm not 100% sure about delete votes - haven't [reached 10K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMjgO.png) yet anywhere :P

Comment: I've seen that part, and interpreted "cycle" as "the required number of votes before an action (closure/reopen/deletion) occurs". Are you sure that "once in each direction in the cycle" means that only one close, re-open and delete can be cast for a specific post?

Comment: @rob - That was my understanding, yes...

Comment: @RobW: delete is different (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/why-is-it-possible-to-vote-for-deletion-undeletion-more-than-once)

Comment: @Lix Thanks, I get it now. Turns out that this question is a duplicate of [Why can't I vote to close a question I've already voted to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137425/why-cant-i-vote-to-close-a-question-ive-already-voted-to-close) (because the deletion vote did not matter).

Comment: +1, but you really need to quit slacking off and get your 10k.