# What happens when people are adamant on closing and not closing a question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

Imagine a situation where there are 10 people 5 of which adamantly want to close a question, the other 5 adamantly want it to remain open.

So the first 5 people cast close votes and the question becomes closed.

Then the next 5 people case reopen votes and the question is reopened.

Now what happens?

Can the first 5 people vote to close again? or can only different users vote to close now?

What happens if the question keeps getting closed and reopened?

Answer (score 4):

After you have cast a close vote, that is it for you with close voting this question. If it is reopened either by other users or a mod you can't cast a close vote again.
For the other way around I don't know, but I guess it is the same.

See also: ["After voting to close, delete and reopen, I can't cast a close vote"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140724/232788)

Quoting the quote:

> Questions can go through multiple close and reopen cycles, but each individual user may only vote once in each direction in the cycle.