# Can't retract dupe Close vote if the post closed in reverse order

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

Recently I casted a Close vote on this post [How to disable sort in DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4502442/2427065) as a dupe of this post [Best way to disable the column header sorting in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4334983/2427065).

Later the moderator Cody Gray closed the other one as a dupe of this post.

If it's confusing, let me explain.

I casted a Close vote on A as dupe of B. Then a mod closed B as a dupe of A.

Now I can't retract my close vote.

I tried it after the mod closed the question.

[image]

But the close vote count changed from 1 to 0. Also The retract button is not there.

I checked it today and saw the same message. I can't retract my Close Vote.

[image]

Since the working of Close is same for all SE sites, I don't think this is an issue pertains only to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Since there is no "(x)" behind "close", there is nothing to retract. There aren't any open close votes anymore.

Comment: @Tom yes but the dialog shows _you have voted to close..._

Comment: Looks like the original question was left opened (thus no more vote count), and you can't vote to close the same question (aka [Why can't I vote to close a question I've already voted to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137425))

Comment: may it is the reason Elias but I am not sure what happened. Can mod's forcefully age away a cv?

Comment: **"yes but the dialog shows you have voted to close..."** - and that is correct, you already voted, so you can't vote again.

Comment: @i-- forgot to ask in chat, when exactly did you cast the close vote, and when exactly did you try to retract it? Close votes age away. After aging away, you can't retract it since there is no vote anymore.

Comment: @Sha check the first image. it shows you voted to close 2 mins ago. I tried to retract within 3 minutes

Comment: So you took the screenshot 6 days ago and kept it? Wasn't sure about that.

Comment: yes. First I think I should raise it in the same day. But then I think it may be status by design. But today, in chat you & Glorfindel confirmed CV can be retracted. So I asked it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no vote to retract. When a question gets closed as a duplicate, the system looks up any duplicate votes on that question pointing back to the now-closed one and immediately clears them. This is done to prevent duplicate circles where two questions are both closed as duplicates of each other. Since the other question being closed as a duplicate of that question is no longer valid, the close vote should no longer exist. Since it's already been cleared, you can't retract it.

The close dialog still tells you *when* you cast your close vote because you can only vote to close a question once. This is the standard behavior any time you've voted to close a question before and you're no longer eligible to cast another close vote on it (such as if the question *had* been closed and then reopened again).